# Is it natural to say "the bar may slip OFF the table" or "the bar may slip ON the table"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

There is a wooden bar leaning on the edge of a table.

Is it natural to say "**the bar may slip OFF the table**" or "**the bar may slip ON the table**"?

Answer (score 2):

To "slip on the table" would mean that the subject would remain on the table, but slip around on its surface.

"The soup dish kept slipping on the table, so we put it on a rubber mat."

Comment: But what if the wooden bar got fallen off the table? would we say "the bar may slip off the table"?

Comment: Yes, if it fell to the ground it would have slipped (or fallen) off the table.

Comment: @Tom Sorry, I thought that usage was obvious, apologies if it's not.